# When fetching data, how do we decide when we should use async api call based on content type

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, asynchronous, fetch

My question is how do we decide whether we should fetch the 100's of comments at once versus something like 20 comments at a time with event listener that trigger more async api calls.

What are standards of the optimial json size that should return from the server? Generalizing further for different mediums like bigger posts, pictures, etc

I'm building a React project that simulate the youtube comment section, not sure whether I should push all the comments into the state first then render them base on client's scroll down. Or should I request more comments base on client's scroll. I suppose its a trade off between server load and client load time. Just curious what the best practice is.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure there is a correct answer to this, as it depends on multiple factors...

Comment: by any chance have you come across any articles on this topic?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say we have a json array of 100000 users

```
{
    id: "1",
    username: "John2020",
    firstname: "John",
    lastname: "Doe",
    age: "35",
    position: "Developer",
}
```

Fetching all data at once and save it in a state 
will overload the VirtualDOM which might cause performance problem
depending on the client's browser and machine.

Best practice is using **Pagination** instead of fetching all data
, fetch by an offset and limit on demand.

You can implement this by infinite scroll or via a classic pagination.